# Android Studio Buttons not Displaying

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I made this dialog for my app that shows up allows you to **delete** the items from db. It used to be a textView and a button which called the function, all in a **linear layout**, which worked good.   Now I changed to a **Relative Layout** so I could add another button on the same line as the other, I also added an editText.
  My problem is that since I added those objects I am not able to see the buttons anymore. the editText and textView are visible.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_deletefood"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.paulcosma.app2.SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Şterge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteEatenFood"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnModifyEatenFood"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnModifyEatenFood"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Modifică"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/btnModifyEatenFood"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtEditValue"
        android:maxLength="6"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This dialog is supposed to show on listView item click. Below is the code I used to show it.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = (HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    final String _name = hmap.get("food");
    final int _id = foodDB.getFoodId(_name);

    AlertDialog.Builder mBuiler = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_deletefood,null);

    final TextView lblFoodDetails = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lblFoodDetails);
    final Button btnDeleteEatenFood = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteEatenFood);

    lblFoodDetails.setText("Aţi ales produsul " + _name + ". Aici puteţi adăuga sau scădea cantitatea printr-o anumită valoare sau puteţi şterge apariţia produsului.");

    mBuiler.setView(mView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = mBuiler.create();

    btnDeleteEatenFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            foodDB.deleteEatenFood(_id);
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,_name+" a fost sters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            updateFoodList(foodDB.getAllEatenFood());
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You can put buttons on the same line with a LinearLayout...

Comment: @cricket_007 even so, why isn't this working?

Comment: 1) Can you show your Java code that loads this layout? 2) You said this is a dialog? Normally, I wouldn't put such large margins on a dialog

Comment: @cricket_007 this is my first android app. I'm still testing stuff

Comment: Can you show the Activity containing the ListView that you should be using `listView.setOnItemClickListener` on?

Comment: @cricket_007 the whole java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that both buttons where placed based on textView's size. When it changed, buttons got placed out of the screen

Bug:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
android:layout_toEStartOf="@+id/lblFoodDetails"
```

Answer (score 0):

This layout file renders the buttons in the Android layout designer as described (see below)

[image: Layout File]

The problem may reside in code.